# Where is Web Site Administration Tool in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I can't find this button.

[image]

And if I add `asp.netwebadminfiles` to the host address in the URL, the page is not found.

How can I open this tool?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

it is on top menu in PROJECT directory

> 

[image]

Comment: why the WSAT opened by this link connected not to my local DB? It makes changes somewhere else but not in the DB that connected to the project. Any idea why?

Comment: here is the good post how to do that: http://www.vssbusinesssolutions.com/KBArticles.aspx?KbArticleID=84

Comment: note that if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet template with the new SimpleMembership provider you cannot use the this tool.  [More info here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Comment: No, it's not. At least not for my existing project (that did have it in previous version of VS).

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you 'long-hover' over a 'asp:LoginView':
[image: 'Long-hover']

and click on the tiny '>', you will get:

[image: LoginView Tasks]

where you can select 'Administer Website'.

This will lead you to the famous Web Site Administration Tool:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the version of Visual Studio 2012 I am using (downloaded at the end of the Release Candidate phase), I can only access the Website Administration Tool in the Website menu in the menu bar at the top, under the command 'ASP.NET Configuration'. The Website menu was only available if I selected the website or one of its content files or folders in Solution Explorer.

By contrast, if I selected the solution in Solution Explorer, the Project menu becomes visible instead of the Website menu, and the ASP.NET Configuration command is NOT available there.

Contact me for screenshots if desired. I have them, but as a newer user, they did not allow me to post them.