# Can't access Asp.Net configuration in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2010 for each ASp .Net Project be it mvc or webforms I could access the Asp .Net configure management website from the solution explorer to create/delete users and roles from the website.

With visual studio 2012 I can't seem to find that option.

Does it require a configured membership provider? I am using a custom membership provider for that.
I only have the membership and role providers configured. Do I need to have the profile provider configured too?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382529/where-is-web-site-administration-tool-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: thank you, found it now, I can't mark it as the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could find this option in the Project menu called ASP.Net Configuration.