# Create ASP.NET Roles and Membership table to my application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I need to create ASP.NET's  Roles and Membership tables to a new DB (SQL Server 2012) that I created. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ASPNET_REGSQL.exe tool in the framework folder to do this for you:

[ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Just run the exe without any switches and it will bring up a GUI for you.

Then use the [ASP.NET Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382529/where-is-web-site-administration-tool-in-visual-studio-2012) for configuration details (icon on top of Solution Explorer panel in VS).

[Web Site Administration Tool Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: How do I determine what my framework folder is. I see about 7 different asp_regsql.exe files on my c drive when I do a search on my c drive.

Comment: Depends on whether you're on 32 or 64 bit ;-)