# Fixing a broken database .NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, database, webforms

Okay so I am working in Web Forms but the problem would also apply to MVC I am assuming since both have the option of creating a users database on project creation. I deleted a data table on accident and updated the database instead of deleting the database itself because I was trying to recreate it with the seed data. I didn't realize that deleting a data table would do something different from deleting the database itself. The only backup I have is pretty old, so I would prefer to use a different way to fix things if that exists. How would I fix things?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you *meant* to delete the database, why not just do that now?

Comment: `I didn't realize that deleting a data table would do something different from deleting the database itself.` I'm not very sure that I understand this phrase - deletion of table... deletes table as expected

Comment: @IlyaBursov So I thought that deleting the table and compiling would make it so that the rest of the database would stay and just that table would be recreated and seeded.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did to try to fix it but when the database was created again and seeded, it continues to lack AspNetRoles. That table was not generated.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` does what you are looking for. Removes the data from the table but leaves the underlying structure. `DELETE FROM` will delete the data, similar to truncate, but also logs the deletes. `DELETE TABLE` removes it from the database completely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152975/create-asp-net-roles-and-membership-table-to-my-application

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it changed some code in the models or code behind automatically when I deleted the table. I took the database from my back up and replaced the flawed one with it and ran it, but still got an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. What I did to fix it was I went to my back up although it could have just been a brand new project, both would have been fine, and I copied the SQL script for the data table that I deleted. Then I went to my broken program and created a new data table in the spot where it was before and replaced the code with the code from the back up. I saved it and hit update and it updated the database for me.