# Where is the Web Application Administration Tool in Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working through an ASP.net tutorial and I'm on this example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_security.htm

Step 1 of the tutorial is the following:

*Step (1) : Choose Website -> ASP.NET Configuration to open the Web Application Administration Tool.*

The thing is, there is no "Website" selection in the menu. I googled to see where it is, and I found this link:

[Where is Web Site Administration Tool in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382529/where-is-web-site-administration-tool-in-visual-studio-2012)

It says that in VS 2012, it is found in the "Project" menu, however, that is not an option in Visual Studio 2015.

Here is my project menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsVsy.png

Can anybody tell me where to find the Web Application Administration tool in Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web?

Comment: It's not included in VS 2013 or VS 2015. You'll need to find a workaround or use an alternative method of creating your users. Why not just write some code to add them?

Comment: It looks like that's what I'll have to do. Whenever I posted the question, I didn't realize that it had been removed until I read Andy's post. I figured that I was probably just over looking it somewhere.